# tikz-uml: How to place a package name inside the package's body?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

Using the command `\umlemptypackage{name}`, it's possible to create simple, empty packages with `tikz-uml`. This leads to a package with its name written in the top left field:

[image: Package variant 1]

Since UML makes it possible (and it looks better for small simple packages), I would like to use this notation, though, with the package name written inside the body of the package:

[image: Package variant 2]

Is it possible to achieve this in `tikz-uml`?

And if not, would it be possible to add custom elements inside a `tikz-uml` object? Thus, I would be able to add text or other graphics myself, like this:

[image: Package variant 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a short look at `tikz-uml.sty` file, I've found that a `package` is defined as two nodes (package name and package name-caption) and there is no option to use an empty name because it's used to identify mentioned nodes.

Once the node is declared you can draw or fill it with `TikZ` commands.

Following code shows some examples. The solution to avoid packages names in top node is tricky. What I've done is to fix the `text` color equal to `fill` color. The text is written, but it's invisible.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlpackage}[fill=blue!30, text=blue!30]{pack}
\begin{umlpackage}[fill=red!30, text=red!30]{pack2}
\node {Pack 2};
\end{umlpackage}
\end{umlpackage}

\begin{umlpackage}[x=3, y=1, fill=green!30, text=green!30]{pack3}
\end{umlpackage}

\node at (pack3.center) {Test 3};

\draw[red] ([shift={(-45:1mm)}]pack2.north west) rectangle ([shift={(135:1mm)}]pack2.south east);

\draw[->] (pack-caption.center) circle (1mm) -- (pack3-caption.center) circle (1mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]